# Right click focus in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Today in my Swing app when I left click, the text area gets focused. When I do a right click on any other text field,the popup menu appears but that text area is not focused. The focus remains on the field left clicked on before. How do I remove the focus from the previous field and make it appear on the field that is right clicked upon ?

```
if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.show(tree, e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
```

Doing this on mouseRelease.

Comment: When you do a left click no text is highlighted. The caret is moved to the point where you did the click.

Comment: So I have to relocate the caret to the text field where perform the right click next then ?

Comment: `when I left click, the text area gets highlighted.` I don't understand your question because you make an invalid statement above. The text is NOT highlighted when you left click so you must have some custom code that does this. So if you want the same thing to happen on a right click then you need to copy that custom code.

Comment: I am guessing you just want right-click to transfer focus to the clicked component.  Use [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow--) for that.  Also, you need to execute the same code in mousePressed and mouseClicked, not just mouseReleased, if you want your code to work on all platforms.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help :( I'm not sure if I'm being clear about my requirement. In Windows machines file explorer, when we perform a right click on a filed, that field gets highlighted, I want similar behavior in my Swing app too. The pop up displays but that text field I click on doesn't get highlighted. Left click works fine. I am new to Swing so I'm sorry if what I'm saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: Indeed you don't mean 'highlight', as this would just mean to mark the text. The right term would be 'focus' .

Comment: Swing apps behave quite strange concerning that. If you have a frame with multiple jtextfields and right-click on the third one to open a popup with say copy-cut-paste, the first field will get the focus and for example take the pasted text. So the user will have to left click into the field to get the focus, than right click to get the popup, then left click on the menu item. Bad for workflow.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant 'focus' instead of 'highlight':

Create a subclass of JTextField, add a mouse listener and force the text field to request focus whenever the mouse button is pressed, released or clicked (three versions to make sure it works on every platform).

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TextFieldRClick extends JTextField {

    public TextFieldRClick() {
        super();
        createMouseListener();
    }

    public TextFieldRClick(int cols) {
        super(cols);
        createMouseListener();
    }

    private void createMouseListener() {
        this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                requestFocusInWindow();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                requestFocusInWindow();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can then create text fields as directly 'new TextFieldRClick()' giving them the ability to get the focus when the user right-clicks them.

I had the same problem, this solved it for me.

**EDIT:** Changed requestFocus() to requestFocusInWindow(). requestFocus() is said to be platform dependent and should no longer be used.