# Right click pop-up menu does not get focus on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox, popupmenu

I have two text fields and one editable combobox in my application using swing.
And first text field one should not have popup menu. But the second ext field  should have popup and combobox should have it too.
I have popup menu ready. But the problem is when I am launching application, 1st text field is in focus and when I do right click on second text field and select paste option from it, paste is done into 1st field.

I tried to add mouse dragged listener to second text field.

```
    txtRoles.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            txtRoles.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

But it didn't worked.

Also I want popup to paste in editable combo-box. But the condition is I want to select all the text available automatically when mouse right clicked.
Is any method available to this ?

Thank you in advance for answering to my question.

Comment: Why not [`setComponentPopupMenu()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu-javax.swing.JPopupMenu-) or check [`isPopupTrigger()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup)?

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513767/right-click-focus-in-swing

Comment: `I tried to add mouse dragged listener to second text field.` why? You are not dragging the mouse. You should be using a MouseListener.

Comment: right click focus on text field is solved.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if i can solve my problem for combobox ?